# Re-using PHP variables

Tags: php, variables

I'm curious about people's opinions on a specific case of re-using PHP variables.

When exploding a comma-delimited string (assuming that the $names variable itself comes from somewhere else and is not used for anything else later on):

```
$names = 'Bob,Jim,Carol';
$nameArray = explode($names);
foreach ($nameArray as $name) { // etc. }
```

Versus:

```
$names = 'Bob,Jim,Carol';
$names = explode($names);
foreach ($names as $name) { // etc. }
```

The second version is quicker to write and less prone to typos, imo, but you could argue that the first version is more readable.  Presumably, PHP has to do some extra work to convert the string variable to an array variable in the second version, but it uses fewer variables.

Performance is probably not much of an issue here. Do people have a strong preference for one method over the other?

Comment: *people's opinions* -> SO off-topic. SO is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: @Rizier123 There might be an industry standard (which to my knowledge there isn't), making the question to not only reflect people's opinions but actually affecting e.g. job searching or such.

Comment: @chelmertz OP is clearly asking for people's opinions, so this can only lead to a discussions and opinions, which are just off-topic

Comment: @chelmertz I thought their might be a strong consensus supporting one over the other. If there were, it would be valuable information for PHP coders (me included). The fact that there is not, imo, is also valuable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is perfectly ok.

However I would still consider this a bad practice, as this may cause confusion among other developers (or even yourself) looking at the code at a later point of time.

I personally tend to use the shorter name for the more important variable, i.e. the one used more often in following lines of code. If the array is more important, I would give the string the name `namesStr`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's matter of style. In some places it might be OK, in some not so much. But why stop there - you can use even different code

```
<?php

$names = 'Bob,Jim,Carol';
foreach (explode(',', $names) as $name) {
    echo $name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And for some this will look bad, for some good.

Answer (score 1):

I use both of them. In the first example, you could give the first variable a detailed name instead of applying a comment somewhere.

I would use the second example if the first variable is too long to fit on one row (if `$names = explode(',', 'Bob,Jim,Carol,...,...,...');` becomes long).

In your simple case, I'd write

```
foreach(explode(',', array('Bob,Jim,Carol')) as $name) { ..
```

But that might not apply too often since your hardcoded values might as well reside in an object's property, a constant or any other source outside of your current scope.

My general thought is to avoid unnecessary variables (those only used once) until the code looks weird which is highly subjective, perhaps due to too many parens or too long rows.